# Web server code to interface with Core Data SQLite file?

Tags: php, iphone, ios, sqlite, core-data

I am building a service where users will integrate my app with a website. Part of the story is that they will upload their Core Data database. Is there a toolkit or library (preferably PHP)  that is equipped to read Core Data sqlite and manipulate them?

Comment: Not sure if it is what you are after but Heroku do a core data back end engine. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ios-core-data-buildpack-app

Answer (score 1):

If it's SQLite then any SQLite client should be capable - the whole point a rDBMS system is that the schema is described by the database, therefore the fact it contains an Apple Core Data model is irrelevant. You've tagged this as [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php), what happenned when you tried to ccess it using PHP?